# Use Fragment Activity when we use Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Do we need to extend the activity class with Fragment Activity when we use fragments? Or we can simply extend it with Activity? I am searching for the answer on the internet but couldn't get the answer please help me......

Thanks in advance,

Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply extend `FragmentActivity` which itself inherits `Activity`.  Each fragment only needs to extend `Fragment`

Comment: if you are targeting Honeycomb or above, Activity contains functionality of FragmentActivity.  FragmentActivity is defined in support library for use on platforms prior to Honeycomb.